# compling C++ program using openCV library

Tags: c++, c, opencv, compilation, using

After the successful installation and build of openCV library,am trying to build C/C++ application as follows :

```
surinder@surinder-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/Downloads/cpp_test$ g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjasper
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtiff
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjpeg
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When i look for libjasper.so its location is :

```
surinder@surinder-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/Downloads/cpp_test$ locate libjasper.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so.1.0.0
```

where am going wrong...how to fix this error.

Comment: Which output are you getting when run the command "pkg-config --modversion opencv". I just wondered the version of opencv and installed correctly.

Comment: surinder@surinder-HP-EliteBook-8440p:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.13.7

Comment: I can only assume because I dont know what you have in your code but your opencv version is very old. Maybe it is because your code has a function which opencv 2.4.13 doesnt support. Installing opencv3.4 or higher is better generally.

Comment: am just compiling an empty application :). When this is fixed,will probably add code to it .

Comment: Add `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` to say where the libraries are and `-ljasper` to say the name.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that worked !!...thanks very much.

Comment: Now if i put code into the application ,it give me linking errors.

Comment: The error is as follows:surinder@surinder-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/Downloads/cpp_test$ g++ main.cpp -o output  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ljasper `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
/tmp/cciU5MRC.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3MatD2Ev[_ZN2cv3MatD5Ev]+0x39): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/cciU5MRC.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv[_ZN2cv3Mat7releaseEv]+0x47): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The code is as follows:#include </usr/local/include/opencv/highgui.h>
#include <iostream>
 using namespace cv;
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  
   cv::Mat image;

  return 0;
}

Comment: Add `--libs` after `--cflags`.

Comment: it's giving this : surinder@surinder-HP-EliteBook-8440p:~/Downloads/cpp_test$ g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -ljasper  main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -o output
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjasper
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibtiff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibjpeg
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Opencv versioned 2.4.13.6 is working properly after installation and am able to run C++ code as :
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` main.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o output